# How do I set the height of an element to the same as another element?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm just starting out with android and trying to make a simple user interface.

I'm using TableLayout and each TableRow is supposed to contain an image and several buttons next to it. I set the width and height of the buttons to wrap_content, which is exactly what I want. Now I want the image to have exactly the same height as the buttons. The image is way bigger, so wrap_content doesn't work.

Obviously I can just adjust the dp value of the image height until it fits, but there has to be an easier way and I guess that pretty much defeats the purpose of using wrap_content in the first place...

Comment: Have you tried set the height on the image to match_parent? I know it sounds crazy, but try it and run it on the device

Comment: Oh well, I guess it wasn't that complicated. Although I really don't understand it. The TableRow is set to match_parent, as is the TableLayout. So why does my image NOT fill up the entire screen? Also, this only works as long as the button whose height I want to match is actually the highest element in the TableRow?

Comment: I Answered it below, please mark it correct so it can be helpful to other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of the image to `match_parent`. Your buttons are doing all the height-sizing work having the `wrap_content` set. When the row gets sized it uses the button height, as they say "you will be as tall as our content", and then when the image is going to be sized, it will use the available height, as specified before by the buttons. Even if the buttons are smaller than the image, the image will still take the available space.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks! The only thing I still don't understand is, why the TableRow is as tall as the content, even when I had it set to match_parent. Isn't that why you would have to use wrap_content?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```